# Short hand for any tuple position None in F#

Tags: f#, tuples

Is there a short hand for the the following pattern in F# or can I effortlessly create one, that is independent of the number of tuple elements?

```
 | (None, _, _,_,_) | (_,None,_,_,_) | (_,_,None,_,_) | (_,_,_,None,_) | (_,_,_,_,None)
```

The idea of the pattern would be a `None` option at any element, to make sure only valid calculations are carried out.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Tuples quickly become cumbersome after about three elements.

Comment: If you find that you need to handle tuples of this size in your logic, you're probably doing something wrong at some earlier stage of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to deal with option tuples on a regular basis, inverting the logic and leveraging a multi-case active pattern may ease the pain. Instead of a test for `None` in any position check for `Some` in all positions.

```
let (|AllSome5|AnyNone5|) = function
| Some(a), Some(b), Some(c), Some(d), Some(e) -> AllSome5(a, b, c, d, e)
| _ -> AnyNone5
// val ( |AllSome5|AnyNone5| ) :
//   'a option * 'b option * 'c option * 'd option * 'e option ->
//     Choice<('a * 'b * 'c * 'd * 'e),unit>

match Some(42), Some(1.0), Some(0uy), Some("abc"), Some('d') with
| AllSome5(a, b, c, d, e) -> () // do something with 42, 1.0, 0uy, "abc", 'd'
| AnyNone5 -> ()                // otherwise
```

Achieving independence of tuple size is technically not impossible, but it ain't pretty. Method overloading combined with statically resolved type parameters will not lend itself to being used as an active pattern, but needs a function call instead.

```
let some4 = function
| Some(a), Some(b), Some(c), Some(d) -> Some(a, b, c, d)
| _ -> None
let some5 = function
| Some(a), Some(b), Some(c), Some(d), Some(e) -> Some(a, b, c, d, e)
| _ -> None
type Foo = Foo with
    static member($) (_ : Foo, (a, b, c, d)) = some4(a, b, c, d)
    static member($) (_ : Foo, (a, b, c, d, e)) = some5(a, b, c, d, e)
let inline foo args = Foo $ args

match foo(Some(42), Some(1.0), Some(0uy), Some("abc"), Some('d')) with
| Some(a, b, c, d, e) -> () // do something with 42, 1.0, 0uy, "abc", 'd'
| None -> ()                // otherwise
```

Answer (score 2):

If all 5 elements are of the same type, you could use a `when` clause like this:

```
| (None, _, _,_,_) | (_,None,_,_,_) | (_,_,None,_,_) | (_,_,_,None,_) | (_,_,_,_,None) -> "none!"
```

Or make a helper function if you need to do it a lot:

```
module Tuple5 =
    let toArray (a, b, c, d, e) = [|a; b; c; d; e|]
```

Of course, you would need to do this for each tuple size. You would use it like this:

```
| x when x |> Tuple5.toArray |> Array.contains None -> ()
```

However, I've never needed a 5 item tuple in F# code where all items have the same type. If that is the case then consider using an array or list instead of a tuple.

Comment: Thank you, but that would only be worth it, if could do it size independent and not homogeneous Type